# Flex - Scroller that wraps a popup window

Tags: apache-flex

Programming in Flex 4.5

I want a scroller to be wrapped around a popup window (based on borderconatiner)

I cant put my scroller correctly.

```
<s:Scroller width="600" height="70%" id="scroller>
    <s:Group id="myGroup">
    // Here is the rest of my code..
    </s:Group>
</s:Scroller>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check [this example](http://tourdeflex.adobe.com/flex4samples/UIControls/OtherControls/Scroller/sample1.html) from Tour de Flex

Right click then View Source.